# Is there a measure extension theorem: extend only to a finitely additive measure?

Tags: measure-theory

as I know, Caratheodory Extension Theorem says that under some condition a set function defined on some class of subsets can be extended to a measure.

Here, a measure is required to be countably additive.
(i.e. $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)$ where $A_i\cap A_j$ is empty for all $i\neq j$)

I wonder if there is an extension theorem which only guarantees a finite additive measure. That is, under some conditions a set function defined on some class of subsets can be extended to a finitely additive measure.
(i.e. $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ if $A\cap B$ is empty)

Does any one know such result? Any reference? Thank you.

Comment: See chapter 3 of _Theory of Charges_ by Rao and Rao, which discusses this problem in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!!